# Access custom props of the current active route using react js and react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a few photo links that link to a single page they belong to. Problem is, I am using the same component in the single page to display the photo but can't figure out how to access the props from the current index so only the photo from the current route shows up. I am using react router and retrieving my data through an api call.

Single.js:

```
 export default class single extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
   super();
 }

static propTypes = {
  posts: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
 };

 render() {
  const { postId } = this.props.params;
  const i = this.props.posts.findIndex((post) => post._id === postId);
  const post = this.props.posts[i];

  return (
    <section className="blog-landing-page">  
      <Photo {...this.props} key={i} i={i} post={post} />
   </section>
     );
  }
}
```

Photo.js

```
  export default class posts extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
     super();
   }
   render() {
     const { post, i} = this.props;
      return (
        <section>
         <Link to={`/post/${post.key}`}>
             <img src={post.image.url} alt='' className="grid-photo" />
         <h1>{post.name}</h1>
         </Link>
       </section>
      );
    }
   }
```

When console logging inside "single.js" I get the following output attached.

```
         console.log(this.props.posts)
```

[image]

Comment: what is in your post array ?

Comment: please be more clear what you want

Comment: I would like to access only the props of the current route I am in.

Comment: your current route is ?

Comment: <Route path='/blog' component={BlogLandingPage} />
      <Route path='/post/:postId' component={Single}  />

Comment: @Codesingh - My post array inside an "index.js" file.           {this.props.posts.map((post, i) => <Photo {...this.props} key={i} i={i} post={post} />)}